# Is it possible to write extension method to format a Textbox for currency in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a `ASP.Net` `Web Form` `TextBox` Control that I am able to change its text format formula to the currency formula but this happens after the user enter the number and causing a postback by method  `OnTextChanged()` 
, but I need this to happen at real time.

Meaning: I need this to happen while user is writing without `Postback`? So should I write an extension method for this?

```
<asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="AutoID" onkeypress="CheckValueEntered(event);" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="0" OnTextChanged="plusEnteredAmount" ID="txtAmount" placeholder="المبلغ" CssClass="form-control a"></asp:TextBox>
```

and below I am changing the text formula  on code behind

```
 txtAmount.Text = enteredAmount.ToString("#,##0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You should do server-side validation encase JavaScript is disabled. To validate it before postback use JavaScript on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at jQuery plugin for masking.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Auto-Format-Currency-With-jQuery.html

here is demo

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Auto-Format-Currency-With-jQuery/

Comment: Could not i achieve this without using jquery?

Comment: @Immortal this library is built on the top of JQuery, so yes, you will have to add JQuery to get this working